# Catch toolbar item event in extjs4 mvc controller

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I want to select Draw Polygon button from mapPanel toolbar in DistrictMap controller via refs for this purpose i use below selector in DistrictMap controller! but it doesn't work and i see undefined in console!

```
Ext.define('FM.controller.DistrictMap',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
refs:[
    {
        selector: 'mapPanel toolbar > #polygonButton',
        ref: 'polygon'
    }
],
init: function(){
    this.control({
        'mapPanel toolbar > button#polygonButton':{
            click: this.drawPolygon()
        }
    });
},
drawPolygon: function(){
     console.log(this.getPolygon());
}
```

i add toolbar to mapPanel with below code.

```
Ext.define('FM.view.DistrictPanel',{
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
initComponent: function(){
    var map = Ext.create('FM.view.MapPanel',{});
    map.setPolygonControl();
    map.setModifyControl();
    map.setSelectControl();
    map.addDocked({
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'top',
            items:[
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Draw Polygon',
                    enableToggle: true,
                    toggleGroup: "draw controls",
                    id: 'polygonButton'
                }
           ]});
```

above selector can't select toolbar items! 
I test `'mapPanel toolbar  #polygonButton'` for selector but it doesn't work! too for `#polygonButton`
why selector can't select toolbar items? although if i use only id `#polygonButton` in selector!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above question because districtPanel view doesn't loaded so selector can't select polygonButton in the mapPanel toolbar for fix this problem you should use controller `onLaunch` function instead of `init` function. so fixed code is:

```
Ext.define('FM.controller.DistrictMap',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
refs:[
    {
        selector: 'districtPanel mapPanel toolbar #polygonButton',
        ref: 'polygon'
    }
],
onLaunch: function(){
    this.control({
        'districtPanel mapPanel toolbar #polygonButton':{
            click: this.drawPolygon
        }
});
},
drawPolygon: function(){
     console.log(this.getPolygon());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector implies that `FM.view.MapPanel` has an xtype of `mapPanel`. Is it really so?

Also don't forget that controller refs and control selectors are just component selectors. You can open a console in your browser and try different selectors with `Ext.ComponentQuery.query()`.

Comment: I add `'districtPanel mapPanel  #polygonButton'` to controller onLaunch function and it can get button but i don't know when i run application click event occurs on button! because i don't click the button!

Comment: @taher Not sure what you mean but I do think you need to read `Ext.ComponentQuery` documentation more thoroughly. Controllers are not magical, they rely on component selectors to work. When you get component selectors right, everything will just work.